Wilson mirror operation
I have this basic Wilson current mirror circuit;

And I'm trying to get my head around how it set's a near equal current in R1 and the load. I think I understand the basic theory, and how the circuit mitigates the Early effect by allowing Q3 to develop whatever voltage needed across it's collector-emitter juntion to allow Q1 and Q2 to regulate current accurately. My lack of understanding is around what happens if the different transistors have different gain values (beta).
If beta is nominally slightly higher for Q2 than Q1 then, for the shared voltage at the bases of Q1 and Q2 of around 0.6V, Q1 would require slightly more base current to meet the current set by R1 (roughly 1.68mA).
I can see how the base current of Q1 will settle on the value set by R1 (given Q3 base current negligible), but how does the mirror remain balanced with Q2 setting the current on the RHS, potentially with a different beta. If it's beta was more than Q1's does it just draw less current into it's base as a result until the bridge balances with the same current on both sides?

Wikipedia gives a pretty detailed explanation of this circuit. Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_current_mirror ?

@OwenM - Question: Are your understanding problems perhaps due to the fact that you assume current control Ic=f(Ib) for the transistors?  Physically speaking, the BJT is a voltage-controlled element Ic=f(Vbe) with Vbe1=Vbe2 (for Q1 and Q2), not requiring Ib1=Ib2.

I got ready to answer "mirroring depends on matched $\beta$", but a quick simulation shows otherwise, and I am surprised. Apparently different $\beta$ has little effect on $I_{C(Q2)}$, and I suspect you are correct that Q2 base current $I_{B(Q2)}$ adapts, being different from $I_{B(Q1)}$, while $V_{BE}$ remains unchanged. I don't know why, yet. Great question.

"...while VBE remains unchanged. I don't know why," The reason is: Both B-E junctions are connected to each other. That is the principle of such a current mirror: Same Vbe makes same collector currents.

@LvW I know why $V_{BE}$ is the same, I don't know why base current isn't.

@Simon Fitch - Ic depends on Vbe only - not on Ib (Shockleys equation)

@LvW That sounds like the answer, to me. Please explain in an answer, because it addresses OP's question directly, why $\beta$ is irrelevant

@Simon Fitch - I hesitated to give a detailed answer because the working principle of the BJT is one of the basics (see also the second comment above),The BJT is a voltage-controlled element, where Ic does not depend on Ib but only on Vbe. (According to the great late B. Gilbert, is the base current Ib nothing else than a "defect" or an “unwanted by-product”). Therefore, we have Ic1=Ic2 for Vbe1=Vbe2 (assumption: equal saturation currents Is).

@PeterJennings thank you, yes, I do understand the wiki article more or less, but afaiks all the analysis on that page is given the stated pre-requiste 'All transistors have the same current gain β' is met. My question stems from seeing in the lab that the mirror still works pretty well when using decidedly un-matched discrete components.

@LvW thank you, I've spent the term analysing transistors with lots of use of  the hybrid parameter model, hie = hfe*r_e so it's likely I'm thinking to much in terms base current. I know Shockleys equation but as the reverse sat current, I_s, is hard to measure we moved on from that quickly, though I can see how it shows how I_c depends only on Vbe. But I_s is presumably different for unmatched devices? If so same V_be, different I_c? Which probably correlates to different beta.. either way thats the aspect I am interested in!

@OwenM - "The value of Is .... depends not only on its geometrical arrangement but also on the doping levels and diffusion depths which govern base thickness. In an integrated circuit, many transistors are made at the same time in one circuit and have virtually identical doping profiles...and they will all have the same Is so that transistors operating at equal base-emitter voltages will have equal collector currents."
(Taken from A. Paul Brokaw: „Building Blocks for Linear IC Designer“ in „Analog Circuit Design“, edited by Jim Williams, Butterworth-Heinemann, 1991)

(continued): The collector current of Q2 will differ from Q1 only by the sum of the two base currents. For high-beta transistors this difference will be small and both collector currents will closely match.

Q1 and Q2 form a current mirror. Its input is Q2 collector, and its output is Q1 collector. Note this mirror's input and output are reversed relative to the whole Wilson mirror including Q3.
Thus, Q3 emitter current is mirrored on Q1 collector. Let's call this current "Im", and approximate (for now) Im1=Im2.

Now the input of the Wilson mirror is Iin. This current splits between Ib3 and Im1.
Intuitively, if Q3 conducts "too much" current, then Iout>Iin. This steals base current from Q3, and Q3 conducts less current.
Thus we have a feedback system, with Q3 playing the role of the output transistor, and Q1-Q2 as a current mirror playing the role of the error amplifier, monitoring Q3's emitter current and controlling Q3 via its base to ensure Iout=Iin.
This means Q3 Vbe is irrelevant.
The fact this is a feedback system means it can be less stable than a standard current mirror, depending on the load and layout.
As with any current mirror, accuracy depends on Vbe matching of the pair Q1-Q2, which is the most important factor. Besides device mismatch, there will be a small error due to the difference in Vce between Q1 and Q2, which is Q3's Vbe.
In a standard current mirror (such as Q1-Q2), the output transistor (Q1) has two roles:

Accurately mirroring the current, which requires stable operating parameters (Vbe, hFe...) thus constant temperature, Vce, low Early effect etc
Handling the full output voltage, which results in Early effect and self heating, introduces changes in hFe and Vbe... which contradicts the previous requirements.

This conflict means if output voltage is high, or has large swings, Early and thermal effects in the output transistor will degrade the accuracy of the simple current mirror.
The Wilson mirror assigns the two roles to two different transistors, just like an opamp is split into precision input stage and output stage. The "precision error amplifier" works at constant Vce, and the output transistor Q3 handles all the output voltage. Performance is improved significantly.
Now about hFe...

Base current of Q1-Q2 comes from current through Q3. Like all standard mirrors, Q1-Q2 mirror is "lossy", as the base current for both transistors comes from the input and is lost to ground without being mirrored.
Both transistors have the same Vbe. If they are identical and have the same Vce then they will be at identical operating points, and thus Ie and Ic are identical. However, current for Q1 and Q2 bases is taken from the input current before it even enters the current mirror. So the base current of both transistors is not mirrored, it is missing in the output.
So the output Im1 is Im2 minus the base currents of both transistors.
hFe matching would matter if the error came from the difference in base currents between the two transistors. But here, the error is the sum of base currents. Thus what matters for accuracy is to have lowest possible base currents, in other words, high hFe.
There is a version of the current mirror with base current compensation (fig.7 in this link) which takes base current separately from the power supply instead of the mirror's input current.

Thanks, I think the paragraph "hFe matching would matter if the error came from the difference in base currents..." is what I was missing...

That makes sense! Glad it helped

"My lack of understanding is around what happens if the different transistors have different gain values (beta)."
That is a perfectly valid issue ... in general. Practically, though, current mirrors are common in integrated circuits. The active areas are physically close to each other, so they share the same doping levels and temperatures, and are quite closely matched. If you look at the Wikipedia article, you will find
"Q1 and Q2 in Fig. 1 are a matched pair sharing the same emitter and base potentials"
The same concerns and explanation apply to op amps as well, where the input differential pair needs to be closely matched, and is practical and reliable due to the active areas on the chip being in close physical proximity. Even with that, layout on analog chips can be an issue due to the need for compensating for thermal gradients.

Quote: "... sharing the same emitter and base potentials" Yes, that is the key sentence (same Vbe).

I think you've misunderstood. "Sharing the same emitter and base potentials" is the easy part - you just connect them together. It's the gains and temperature coefficients that are the problem.

@ WhatRoughBeast - I think, I fully understood your point. It was my intention only to underline the fact (and the importance of) Vbe1=Vbe2 for controlling the collector currents. Rememeber: In the question we can read: "... how does the mirror remain balanced.... with a different beta".  (They still have the current-control model in mind).

Basic idea
A Wilson current mirror consists of a basic current mirror connected in the negative feedback loop of an additional transistor.
How it maintains a constant current

I think I understand the basic theory, and how the circuit mitigates the Early effect...

The negative feedback effectively mitigates disturbances of various origins, such as β variations and the Early effect. When the output current tries to decrease, the output transistor starts to conduct more and restores the current (the colorful illustration below is taken from my article dedicated to this unique feature of the famous circuit solution).

How it keeps currents equal

And I'm trying to get my head around how it set's a near equal current in R1 and the load.

In a simple current mirror, the output current is smaller than the input current by "two base currents" (Iout = Iin - 2Ib). In the Wilson current mirror, an additional transistor takes away "one base current" from the input current and adds it to the output current. As a result of this trick, the output current is exactly equal to the input current.
I have attached two more illustrations below from another of my articles dedicated to this unique feature of the Wilson current mirror. Since the negative feedback inverts the operation of the simple current mirror (interchanging its input and output), I have mirrored the circuit diagram horizontally in the first image for clarity.

The second image presents a stylized representation of current flow paths, where the line thickness is proportional to the current's magnitude.

Building and exploring the circuit
Let's now trace the evolution of the current mirror by building and investigating it step by step using CircuitLab. Since all currents are of interest, the circuit would become cluttered with ammeters if we decided to measure them all. Therefore, we can settle for only the most important (input and output) currents.
To simplify the circuits even further, we can represent the resistors by ammeters by assigning them the same internal resistance; that is why there are these strange notations (Rin=10k and RL=5k). Note that this does not introduce any measurement error.
Simple current mirror
Varying Rin (Iin): We can easily adjust the input current by changing the value of the resistance Rin.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The graph is nonlinear because the resistance is in the denominator of Ohm's law. As can be seen, there is a difference of 2Ib between the input and output current.

Varying RL (IL): Then let's vary the load resistance to see how the simple current mirror will react to this intervention.

simulate this circuit
When RL changes from zero to 10 kΩ, the voltage drop across Q2 varies from Vcc to zero and the collector (load) current slightly changes (known as Early effect). The remedy is to introduce negative feedback...

Horizontally flipped current mirror: Then let's prepare the current mirror by flipping it horizontally...

simulate this circuit
Wilson current mirror
... and then including it in the feedback loop.
Varying Rin (Iin): Now, when changing Rin, Q3 adjusts its collector current to be equal to the input current while maintaining its base voltage at 1.3 V (VF2 + VF3 = 2VF).

simulate this circuit
The two curves almost coincide.

Varying RL (IL): When RL changes from zero to 10 kΩ, the voltage drop across Q2 varies from Vcc to zero but the collector (load) current does not change.

simulate this circuit
In more detail, when the current through the load attempts to decrease, the Q3 emitter current and consequently its replica through Q1 also decrease. As a result, the voltage drop across Rin decreases, the base voltage of Q3 increases, and the current is restored.

Analogy
The mechanism of this regulation is the same as that of a common emitter stage with an emitter resistor Re. We can imagine that Re is moved to the place of Rin and a constant voltage drop across Rin is maintained using a copy of the Q3 emitter current.

simulate this circuit

